# How can I ensure that my AVCaptureSession has enough time to run?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession, avcapture

I need to ensure that my AVCaptureSession runs for 15 seconds before being stopped. How could I go about doing this? I'm hesitant about using *wait* or *sleep* because I'm fairly sure that it would halt the intake of input. What can I use to wait 15 seconds before I run the stop command?

Sample code:

```
[self.session startRunning];
// wait 15 seconds 
[self.session stopRunning];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep would indeed bring everything to a screeching halt. Don't do that.

You could use a call to dispatch_after:

```
[self.session startRunning];
// wait 15 seconds 
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
  15 * NSEC_PER_SEC), 
  dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.session stopRunning]; 
});
```

Another alternative would be to set up a CADisplayLink and test to see if 15 seconds has elapsed on each call, but the above should be fine unless you need millisecond accuracy.

Comment: I tried this, but while debugging, the compiler still immediately goes to the stopRunning line.

Comment: Why do you think it does that?

Comment: I don't know, have you any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I've actually figured it out. I just reimplemented your code and it worked as expected. Thanks for the help!